# How to use Date Format Converter in xpath?

Tags: xpath, date-conversion

How to use Date Format Converter in xpath? Refer below XML and x-path for further reference.

**XML:**

```
<FORM>
            <STRT_DT>2020-01-01</STRT_DT>
</FORM>
```

**X-path I used:**

```
//FORM/STRT_DT/tib:format-date("YYYY-MM-DD",tib:parse-date('DD-Mmm-YYYY'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we change your xml to:

```
<FORM>
            <STRT_DT>2020-12-31</STRT_DT>
</FORM>
```

then this xpath expression

```
format-date(//FORM/STRT_DT, '[D01]/[M01]/[Y0001]')
```

EDIT:
or this

```
string(format-date(//FORM/STRT_DT, '[D01]/[M01]/[Y0001]'))
```

will output:

```
31/12/2020
```

Comment: Actual Output:
String='31/12/2020'

Expected:
31/12/2020

Any idea on expected result?

Comment: @TenkasiSubramanian - Well, that depends on your xpath engine, but just in case see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Check this if you want the output in `dd/mmm/yyyy` format.

```
string(format-date(//FORM/STRT_DT, '[D01]/[MNn,3-3]/[Y0001]'))
```

[image]